# Ruby - File for Enums

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

In C# i'm used to create a file called "Enums.cs" and in there define all Enums my app will require... I think it's easier to do it. Now that taking on Ruby, I read and choose the `module` approach to defining enums because i can associate a int to a "word", like:

```
module ContractType
  Undefined = 0
  Internship = 1
  CLT = 2
  Contractor = 4
end
```

Now how can I have my "User" model expose a property like `newGuy.CurrentContractType = ContractType.Internship`?!?

Do I `import` the module? `extend`? Or should I reference the `GlobalEnums.rb` file where all the enums are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Simply `require` the `GlobalEnums.rb` module at the top of your file and then refer to the module and constant like this:

```
newGuy.currentContractType = ContractType::Internship
```

You'll note that in Ruby `::` is used to refer to a constant in a namespace (class or module), rather than `.`. If you have more than one level of nesting, you just chain the `::`s:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class Baz
      Qux = "quux"
    end
  end
end

p Foo::Bar::Baz::Qux
# => "quux"
```

P.S. I suggest glancing through a Ruby style guide [such as this one](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide), in particular the [Naming section](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming). With rare exceptions<sup>†</sup>, method and variable names in Ruby are `snake_case`. Module and class names are `CamelCase` and other constants are usually `SCREAMING_CAMEL_CASE`.

With that in mind, a seasoned Rubyist would probably write your code like this:

```
module MyApp
  module ContractType
    UNDEFINED = 0
    INTERNSHIP = 1
    CLT = 2
    CONTRACTOR = 4
  end
end

# Assuming this is somewhere inside the MyApp namespace...
new_guy.current_contract_type = ContractType::INTERNSHIP
```

<sup>†</sup>For example, strict conversion methods like `Integer(n)` and shortcut constructors like [`URI(str)`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-c-URI) or [`Nokogiri::XML(str)`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri#XML-class_method).

Comment: should i `require 'GlobalEnums.rb'` or `require 'ContractType'`? does it matter if its on a different folder?

Comment: In Ruby the argument you pass to `require` should correspond to the name of the file, so (depending on the path to that file) it should be `require 'GlobalEnums.rb'`.